# Exception thrown when parsing seemingly correct date time

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am using the `DateTime.ParseExact` method to parse a date-time. However, why does the following fail and throw an exception?

```
string input = "100206 2330";
string format = "ddMMyy hhmm";
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Judging from the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) article on MSDN, the format is correct for this input string. I am very confused.

Thanks in advance,

Sterren

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["hh"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) is a 12-hour clock hour specifier (01-12). You want ["HH"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) to cope with "23".

```
string format = "ddMMyy HHmm";
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems I did not read the documentation deeply enough.

Answer (score 1):

For 24 hour clock, you have to use `HH` and not `hh`

```
string format = "ddMMyy HHmm";
```